# Configure Jetty to run a custom filter before filters in war file's web.xml run

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I have a third party .war file that I run on a Jetty server. I need to run code for logging purposes before the filters defined in the .war file's deployment descriptor run. The code needs to have access to the incoming request and the response object and to the context of the logger that runs for the app in the war.

Is there a way to do this in Jetty's xml configuration file? I don't want to touch the war file due to concerns about license.

I could override the deployment descriptor which would allow me to add custom filters but I believe these would then run after the filters in the war. I could also use a request customizer but that doesn't give me access to the response which I also need to edit.

I tried adding a handler to a HandlerCollection before the handler with the org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext that runs the war but it doesn't seem that I have access to the web app's logger's context...

Is there any way to do this? So before the web app's servlet executes run a piece of code that can access the incoming request and the response and the web app's context?

Comment: What do you want to log from the request/response? (it matters, as there's multiple ways to accomplish this, each with it's pros/cons)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I want to take a transaction id (like 123-456) from the incoming request, add a segment to it (123-456-789) and put the result to the web app's logger's context through slf4's MDC.put(key, value) so that the logs generated by the app show that id. I want to do this before the app's filters or servlet run so that if they generate logs, the id is included.  I want to also set this id to the response's header. As said, I don't want to touch the app's war file to do this.

Comment: Based on your statement, I think option 3 (in my below answer) is your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

To access the raw `Request` and `Response` at the various stages of their lifecycles, use the [`HttpChannel.Listener`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.42.v20210604/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpChannel.java#L1089-L1257) (make sure you read the javadoc/apidoc to understand what each event means).

**Option 2:**

To add a handler in the `WebAppContext`, before the Session/Security handling, but after other handlers, use [`WebAppContext.insertHandler(HandlerWrapper)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.42.v20210604/jetty-servlet/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.java#L655-L660).

**Option 3:**

Create a [web-fragment servlet jar](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/servlet-30-web-fragmentxml) that represents your servlet `Filter`, and add it to the `WebAppContext.setExtraClassPath(String)`, which will be picked up and added to the actual webapp's startup.

**Option 4:**

Create a custom `RequestLog` implementation (that you add to `Server.setRequestLog(RequestLog)` that is notified once the request AND response are complete, so you can log the state of the request/log to whatever source you want.

**Option 5:**

Use one of the existing `RequestLog` implementations to log the details you desire to the console in the format you desire. (Look at the combination of [`CustomRequestLog`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.42.v20210604/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.java) and [`Slf4jRequestLogWriter`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.42.v20210604/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLogWriter.java))